# How to know if .fsx script being run by .NETCore/.NET5 or by legacy framework?

Tags: .net, scripting, f#, .net-5

My .fsx scripts are kind of old so they only work with .NET4.x, which means I need to run them with the `fsharpi` command in macOS.

Now I'm thinking to start migrating them to `dotnet fsi`; however, ideally I can find a way to run them in both ways for a while, in a transition period.

So I was hoping that, inside them, I could do some kind of conditional code like this:

```
#if NET5_0
System.Console.WriteLine "we're running in dotnet fsi, yay"
#else
System.Console.WriteLine "we're running with fsharpi, legacy"
#endif
```

But it doesn't work, surprisingly (and I say surprisingly because the define `NET5_0` is being mentioned in many documentation pages). Any other idea of how I could detect this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `System.Environment.Version` will give you the info you need:

```ml
if System.Environment.Version.Major >= 5 then
    System.Console.WriteLine "we're running in dotnet fsi, yay"
else
    System.Console.WriteLine "we're running with fsharpi, legacy"
```

It looks like `NET5_0` is only defined for C#.

Comment: unfortunately this works for conditional code but not for preprocessor directives like #load, #r, etc. :( any other idea for the latter?

Comment: Good point. Here's an idea: You can define `NET5_0` yourself when running a script from the command line: `dotnet fsi --define:NET_50`. Then your original code (`#if NET5_0`) should work.

Comment: mmm, I guess I'll do the opposite: use `fsharpi --define:LEGACY_FRAMEWORK` so that people that use NET5 or newer don't need to poke with flags